# Building Json Newtonsoft Jarray

Tags: json, json.net

I have hours stuck on this, I dont know why I lose my json, with lose I mean it has the 'structure' but not the values. I am trying to return a JArray with JObjects of the Newtonsoft  .Json library. this is a simple example, I am trying to do this with Linq, but get the same results.

I am using asp mvc, I took [this](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeWithLinq.htm) example

My controller:

```
JArray jsonTest = new JArray(
                new JObject
                    {
                      {"Title", "hello"},
                      {
                        "Author", new JObject
                          {
                            {"Name",  "hello"},
                            {"Twitter", "hello"}
                          }
                      },
                      {"Date",  "hello"},
                      {"BodyHtml",  "hello"},
                    },
                    new JObject
                    {
                      {"Title", "hello"},
                      {
                        "Author", new JObject
                          {
                            {"Name",  "hello"},
                            {"Twitter", "hello"}
                          }
                      },
                      {"Date",  "hello"},
                      {"BodyHtml",  "hello"},
                    }
            );

        return Json(jsonTest,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and I get:

[image]

as you can see my structure is there(2 objects, second object is an array with 2 elements), but i have no data in it.

I tried jsonTest.tostring() but I get an array of each char in my string.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the two JObjects into an Jarray

like

```
 JObject obj1=new JObject();

 JObject obj2=new JObject();

 JArray arr=new JArray();

  arr.Add(obj1);
  arr.Add(obj2);

  return arr.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```